# How to create a partially expanding/collapsing html table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html-table

I am trying to improve on an old school "Top Screens" page that we currently have.  It shows the top 30 in a plain old html table.  I want to be able to generate the table with the top 100, but only show the top 20 on page load and then have an expand/collapse button.  I have found plenty of examples of fully expanding and collapsing tables and subtables, but I have yet to find an example of partially doing one like I need.

It is currently a very simple 2 column table with headers and minimal CSS styling and JS.  I would like to keep it to plain JS if possible, but I do have the JQuery library available to me, I am just not very familiar with it.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

EDIT

I apologize for what ended up being a relatively easy solution with JQuery, but I am very new to it.  After reading through the API docs some more I found the :gt() selector that when combined with toggle() lead to an elegant solution which I am adding for anyone who may be interested.

I added the "collapse" class to my <tbody> so the <thead> would not be affected or counted.

```
// Hide extra rows on load.
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".collapse").find('tr:gt(19)').hide();
});

// Toggle extra rows on click.
$(".collapse").click(function(){
    $(this).find('tr:gt(19)').toggle();
});
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn what we expect from questions here. Please be aware that we do not provide from-scratch coding service here. Please show us what you've tried already, how it failed and we might be able to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplelest way to do this would be with jQuery, as you could use the `.toggle()` method.

In my example I've chosen to only show the first 3 results, so that the code isn't too long.

See my comments in the code to understand what's going on.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button#sh").click(function() {
    $("tr.row:nth-child(n+5)").toggle();
  });
});

//Here jQuery listens for a click on the button with id "sh", and when clicked, 
//either shows or hides the rows selected by the CSS selector, which is the same as 
//the one that hid the rows in the CSS section.
```

```css
tr.row:nth-child(n+5) {
  display: none
}
/* Here all rows after the 4th one will be hidden on load. So you have 1 row for the 
header, then 3 rows of data, 3+1=4, so row 5 and on will be hidden. */
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Here jQuery is included -->

<button id="sh">Show/Hide</button>
<!-- Here the button that will show and hide the rows is set. -->

<table border="1">
  <tr class="row">
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Number</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row">
    <td>Name 1</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row">
    <td>Name 2</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row">
    <td>Name 3</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row">
    <td>Name 4</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row">
    <td>Name 5</td>
    <td>5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="row">
    <td>Name 6</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```